# How to specify the option contact all update sites while installing plugins from command line for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, command-line, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install few plugins through command line using:

```
eclipse.exe -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository <repository> -installIU <features id>
```

Now during installing few features it shows **Missing requirements**. This can be resolved in eclipse install software UI by clicking on Contact all update sites, and i noticed that it needs the repository: 
Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno.
Now how do i do this via command line? I don't know what are feature groups of all missing requirements!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a comma separated list of repositories as the argument to `-repository`. Looking at the install dialog source the 'contact all sites' option just seems to do that.